# Something is doing 100% I/O during Windows 10 boot

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I boot up Windows 10 something is taking up so much I/O time that I can't do anything for about 10 minutes. So I ran Resource Monitor (via Task Manager) and found that the system is using a very high I/O rate. I can't see which file it is. Note that this happens before I login.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you should be able to see which process (including system) is using which file in the resource monitor. Check this screenshot : https://s17.postimg.org/ja8o3myzz/Capture.png

Comment: I have the same problem. When I search the above people, it doesn't seem like this question is a duplicate. For myself I would like to keep this question open as it is much more direct. I also tried "Resource Monitor (via Task Manager)" as he suggested above but that does not say which file is being accessed at 100%.